# What can cause this Java behaviour?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

My project generates some text/binary files. If I run it normally, some files will have a pretty low size ( which indicates something went wrong ). If I run it from debug mode ( stepping through code ), the files will be generated correctly.

What can cause this behaviour? I'm pretty sure I don't have any unclosed files.

EDIT: I've gone through the code in a more focused way, and I've found the problem. At one point in time, the files get compressed, and this explains the decrease in size. I'm stupid :)
A moderator can close this question if he sees fit.

Comment: Do you have some code to post?

Comment: have you tried to call the compiler via commandline, or occurs this behaviour just as you build within eclipse?

Comment: The code is not multithreaded, and there are way too many classes.

Comment: Tried to ran it via commandline, same behaviour occurs.

Comment: Can you try running with debug enabled, but without setting any breakpoints? A successful run would indicate a strange interaction with the JIT compiler.

Comment: Ok, so running with debug ( and no breakpoints ), I get the same result as with running normally: low size files. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
System.gc();
try { Thread.sleep(4000); } catch (Exception e) {}
System.gc();
```

...at the end of your program.  If the problem goes away then you *did* forget to close() a file.  The above code is no solution, it is a **hacky** attempt to increase the likelyhood finalizers will run.

Comment: I'd definitely be tempted to add logging/printlns to debug the problem (old school style!)

Comment: ...or you could try a different JRE or version of Java, you never know, it could be a bug.

Comment: In fact, what is the output of java -version for the JRE you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Is your code multithreaded? Are you trying to read something that you haven't given another thread a chance to finish constructing, which doesn't manifest when you're stepping through it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you call some kind of "read" method, to read from a file, for example, and assume that you will always get back the number of bytes that you request?